# How to specify Azure directory to register Power BI native app

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to setup Power BI embedded integration with our Azure Portal. I have an organizational login to our Azure Portal and have access to two directories. The default directory contains all of our Azure SQL Databases and our subscription. The second directory does not contain any subscription.

When I go to https://dev.powerbi.com/apps to register a Power BI application I am never given a choice as to which directory I want to associate with the Power BI service. After I enter in the details of my Power BI application, select my permissions and click Register App I get the Client ID. However the Power BI application is registered in the second directory, the one without any subscription, with Azure.

The first Azure directory, the one with the subscription, is set as my default directory, yet power be registers the Power BI app in the directory without a subscription. How do I force the registration to take place in the first directory, the one with the subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the registration in the first directory, you need to register in the first directory by using the member account in the first directory.

Comment: I have a user account in both directories. Both use the same email address but I cannot determine if they are organizational or individual accounts. I don't know where the second directory (the one without any subscriptions) came from. I think our portal admin set it up. I appear to be the only user in the directory without any subscriptions. Is there a way to delete this directory so Power BI doesn't use it? I need Power BI to go in the directory that contains all our subscriptions.

Comment: As a user in the directory, you cannot delete the directory. You can contact your admin to delete your account from the directory with no any subscriptions.